# Formatting numeric and string values in CSV with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, string, csv, nginx, formatting

Given a row of CSV, like this:

```
23,an unquoted string,"a string with a comma, in the string", "another string", 33.0000000001, 2.0
```

Using NJS (NGINX Javascript -- meaning, I can't rely on NPM packages, and just a subset of vanilla javascript, but I'm OK with copying and pasting code from packages if needed), I'd like to end up with a string-representation of a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[23, "an unquoted string", "a string with a comma, in the string", "another string", 33.0000000001, 2.0]
```

I haven't been able to use JSON.parse, since that can't handle unquoted strings. It's looking more and more I'll have basically manually parse the CSV, doing something like:

Iterate through the line of CSV until I hit an unquoted comma, try to parse the value as a float or integer, or otherwise quote it.

The code will end up getting pretty hairy, and worse: it has to work on tons of CSV data. Large rows, many rows. Many MB of rows every second.

Is there an easier, better way to end up processing my CSV to get it into the form I want it?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick Google search for "npm csv parser" turns up some results.

Comment: Whoops, edited to mention I'm using NJS (NGINX javascript).

Comment: Also: unlike most CSV parsers, I don't want to map headers to column values, just format CSV text in a certain way.